# Execution failed for task ':app:compileProdReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > Could not find tools.jar

Tags: jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I have a jenkins job, which invokes a gradle script. In this job, I have first a shell script:

[image]

This script should adjust the file `local.properties`. As you can see, I also added the export of two system variables for Java.

After that shell script, I run gradle like this

[image]

But when running this job, I get the error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileProdReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre contains a valid JDK installation.
```

I have a RedHat system (`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)`) and both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK are installed. As far as I know, this shouldn't be a problem.

But why does the Jenkins job does not use the Oracle JDK one when I set `JAVA_HOME` and the gradle property `org.gradle.java.home`?

If there are more information needed, I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

When you export the variables in the first shell, they won't persist outside of that shell's execution. It is the same as running a shell (bash, zsh, ksh), running some commands, then exiting the shell. Your variables will not exist outside of that shell.

To set JAVA_HOME properly, you will either need to add an use a plugin that will allow you to inject environment variables in the "Build Environment" section of your config (I can't remember the name of the plugin off the top of my head), or even easier, just add a global tool (Manage Jenins -> Global Tool Configuration) that points to your java on the local machine and then reference that tool in your freestyle job config. It will set JAVA_HOME for you.

Comment: Did this help with your situation?